# GoJS undo a change of category property that is binding to the shape fill property

Tags: bind, categories, fill, undo, gojs

I need to change the category value dinamically.

The code:

```
diagram.startTransaction('changing state: ' + node.data.text);
model.setDataProperty(node.data, 'category', 'stateInitial');            
diagram.commitTransaction('changing state: ' + node.data.text);
```

Node Template:

```
$(go.Shape, 'RoundedRectangle',
    { stroke: null , strokeWidth: 0 },
    new go.Binding("fill", "category", function(category){

         if( category == 'stateInitial'){
              return '#99AE3B';
          }
          else if(category == 'stateFinal'){
              return '#E53935';
          }
          return '#6699CC';
      })
    ), . . .
```

This works OK, the node change its colour dinamcally.

But, After doing this:

```
diagram.undoManager.undo();
```

The node switch to previous category in the model (this is OK) but I don't see the change of colour back to the previous colour.
Only diagram.rebuildParts() method works, but I can't use it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Categories (templates) are special. Try using [Model.setCategoryForNodeData](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#setCategoryForNodeData) instead when changing node categories.

If you are not changing node templates, pick a different data property name than "category", since it has other meanings in GoJS models.